# Redirect file to folder in web.config

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

having a bit of trouble here, I'm working on a web.config file to perform a URL redirect from a file to a folder. I have the following:

```
<rule name="redirect fleet/cats.asp" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^fleet/cats.asp$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.ccy.com.au/availability/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Which redirects:
/fleet/cats.asp to /availability/cats.asp

What I want to achieve is:

/fleet.cats.asp to /availability/

What am I missing to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to remove {R:1} on the action attribute. that way I can redirect from a page to a directory. Thanks me!